# What is the best method for making mutiple wireframes derived from the same data?

Tags: gui-design, wireframe

I currently have to make 3 wireframes from the same data, I find it to be a bit daunting, as I feel I have spoken for the optimal way to do things on the first wireframe, and can't seem to think up any other viable options.

What is the best way to think of different ideas?

Comment: What your data is about? What screen do you have now?

Comment: There are many ways to brainstorm. This question seems pretty broad. It'd help to know why you are being asked to design 3 wireframes of the same data.

Comment: what @DA01 said, it's impossible to provide a real answer with such limited information

Comment: Go on a vision quest? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbccrO8qKog

Answer (score 1):

The *must show 3 examples* logic is an awful remnant from ad agencies where the thought was that it's always best to give clients 3 options to choose from because:

- it makes it look like you did a lot of work
- it gives the client the perception that it's *their* idea by being a part of the choosing process
- it offers up a way to determine the direction a client wants to go in when they aren't entirely clear up front.

Of those bullet points, only the 3rd one is a true design process benefit. The other 2 are just sales bullshit.

Unfortunately, a lot of people still subscribe to that bullshit. And it's not usually good for design.

Sometimes it is, and the alternatives come naturally and hey, that's great! Go with it.

But when it doesn't come naturally--often because it's fairly clear that based on the requirements there really *is* only one *best* option, then you just gotta get the barn shovel out and start flinging. At that point, just randomly create two variations of what you already have for the sake of saying you did 3. Make the sales folks happy. Keep your job for another week. :)

Answer (score 0):

Analyse the data from different perspectives or use-case scenarios.

For example, your data maybe in the form of TV schedules - there may well be a single optimum way to layout a TV guide but what if your user is only interested in a particular time of day? or a particular type of TV show? or wants to know what was on yesterday? - That's likely to yield three different ways of examining the data and, therefore, 3 different optimum solutions.

What you're really being asked to do is find more scenarios where the end user might want to view the data in a different way.